# Unity 2D: How would I go about making a block that shoots when the player touches it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am making a 2D platformer in Unity and I want to make a block that works very similarly to the [shooting blocks from Kid Chameleon](http://kidchameleon.wikia.com/wiki/Evanescent_block). When they are touched by the player, they shoot from what every direction the mark is on and the bullet can hurt the player and enemies, destroy crates and activate other shooting blocks. Can some one tell me how I can achieve this because I have no idea where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start you can use `OnMouseDown()` event for detecting a click(or touch) on an object and then you can Instantiate a bullet object from block and give it's rigidbody a velocity to move towards that. and you can use `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)` event for every Gameobject that you want to detect collision and do your job.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've follow a few tutorials on what you have said and I've manage to get the projectile to drop out of the bottom on the block. Any idea how I would be able to get it to fire out the side?

Comment: Never mind, I've used a different technique. Instead, I made an empty game object and made the bullet a child of that.  When the player touches the block the animator the the bullet makes it fly to the right. Because each block will only need to fire once, it works. However, I'm having a few problems getting the block to activate when it's touched by an other object. I've gave all the objects that I want to activate it a tag of ShootBlockAct and I have added this to my script 'if(Other.gameObject.tag == "Player" | Other.gameObject.tag == "ShootBlockAct")' (Hold on, character limit)

Comment: However, the bullets don't activate other blocks. Some methods for getting them to fire work, such as pushing a block on top of them, but the bullets don't work. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you can give bullets a tag for example `bullet_tag` and in any block `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)` event check for this collision with `if(c.gameObject.tag == "bullet_tag")` statement and do what ever you want